# Converter Ano para dois digitos

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net

Como converter DateTime.now.year para dois digitos?
Ex: 2021 to 21

Meu code:

```
Dim ok As String = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString("yy")
shortyear.text = ok
```

Imprime "yy"

Comment: faça apenas `Dim ok As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yy")` veja o [exemplo](https://ideone.com/6mLfl5)

Comment: Muito obrigado, testei e funcionou tambem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pronto, consegui resolver o problema da maneira mais facil.

```
Dim TimeFormat As String = "yy"
 Sub Yearget()
    yearprint.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(voyagedate.Value).ToString(TimeFormat)
End Sub
```